# Laravel WHERE clause with AND

Tags: mysql, laravel

How can I concatenate WHERE and AND in laravel?

I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM sales WHERE created_at >= $startingDate AND created_at < $endDate
```

I tried like this:

```
return DB::table('sales')
->where('created_at', '>=', $startingDate)
->where('created_at', '<', $endDate)->get();
```

but doesn't reach the result I want.

If I concatenate these two WHERE clauses, is it the same as WHERE (something) AND (somethingelse) ?

My goal here is to get data between those dates, but including the last day.

I also tried whereBetween('created_at', [$startingDate, $endDate]) but it does not include the last day.

How can I do this?

Comment: actually `where()` are chained using `AND`, so ensure `$startingDate` and `$endDate` are formatted in the way MySQL understands it.

Comment: Which values are you using for `$startingDate` and `$endDate`? It could be a date format issue.

Comment: Thank you, but I think the values of $startingDate and $endDate are correct, the only problem is that I need to add one more day to the ending date if I want the sales from the ending date. The values are: "16-02-2018" and "18-02-2018"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My goal here is to get data between those dates, but including the last day.

Use the `endOfDay()`:

```
Sale::whereBetween('created_at', [$startingDate, $endDate->endOfDay()])->get();
```

I assume that these variables are Carbon instances. If not, do this first:

```
$startingDate = Carbon::parse($startingDate);
$endDate = Carbon::parse($endDate);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Could I ask you one more way to get the end of day without Carbon? I'm using this format: "28-02-2018'

Comment: @GabrielAugusto you can use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) if you don't want to use Carbon. Or you can add time to the `28-02-2018` string manually. But it's a bad idea and you should really use Carbon.